# Android: how to show images in ImageSwitcher

Tags: android

I have an array of files contained in the sdcard: i would like to show an item in a ImageSwitcher but could not find the SetImageBitmap but only SetImageResource, but i have not these in res folder.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this below code instead of setImageBitmap. I think you have files in array.

```
imgSwitcher.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(filename));
```