# Android: How to: set the Image of ImageSwitcher by a Bitmap? setImageBitmap doesn't exist?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, imageswitcher

i can't find setImageBitmap from ImageSwitcher. is there a way to set it by a bitmap?

**UPDATES1**
then i found this -> [set Image from file URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089042/android-how-to-show-images-in-imageswitcher)

But my case is, i have to draw something in the bitmap before it set to ImageSwitcher. So, is there no way to set it via bitmap? if no way, i have to output the image file from modified bitmap then use setImageURI. But this is wasting of memory.

**UPDATES2**
Alternative: Is there a way to dynamically store the image file from sdcard to R.drawable or R.raw to generate resource/drawable id. Then use it to setImageResource or setImageDrawable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can wrap your Bitmap in [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) and use [ImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

Comment: now i can set the bitmap via bitmapdrawble. but the imageswitcher's view size change to bitmap size. before it was on fullscreen.

Comment: Are you using wrap_content for the ImageSwitcher and ImageViews in it? Could you post your layout and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: would you suggest me the efficient way to set ImageSwitcher image using BitmapDrawable (the bitmap must be mutable)? I am receiving out of memory error

Comment: BitmapDrawable should not add much overhead compared to a simple Bitmap. So I can only suggest you to explicitly recycle your bitmaps when you no longer need them. I developed a slideshow apllication recently and used out animation's callback to recycle a bitmap when it goes away.

Answer (score 13):

you can convert bitmap into drawable and assign drawable to image switcher as

```
Drawable drawable =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
mSwitcher.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```